# How do I get the switch statement to work when there is an error in switch case

Tags: go, switch-statement

based on user input from command line, switch case returns rating for an integer. Since command line arguments are of type string, I first convert it to `int` and then use it in switch.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "reflect"
  "strconv"
)

func main() {
 rating, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1])
 fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(rating))
 switch rating {
  case rating >= 2100:
    fmt.Println("grand master")
  case rating >= 1900:
    fmt.Println("candidate master")
  case rating >= 1600:
    fmt.Println("expert")
  case rating >= 1400:
    fmt.Println("pupil")
  case rating < 1400:
    fmt.Println("newbie")
  }

}
```

Now there is error on rating >= 2100, for all comparisons rather. It goes as follows:

```
cannot convert rating >= 2100 (untyped bool value) to intcompilerInvalidUntypedConversion
```

Not able to understand how to resolve this.

Please help!

Comment: You wanted `switch { case (various boolean tests on rating here)... }`, not `switch rating { ... }`.

Answer (score 8):

If you use a `switch` expression, you have to use `case` expressions where  they are comparable. [Spec: Switch statements:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements)

> For each (possibly converted) case expression `x` and the value `t` of the switch expression, `x == t` must be a valid [comparison](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators).

That is, if you use `switch rating { ... }`, then you only need to specify the integer values, e.g. `2100`, and not a comparison like `rating >= 2100`.

Obviously you don't want single values but ranges, so omit the switch expression:

```
switch {
case rating >= 2100:
    fmt.Println("grand master")
case rating >= 1900:
    fmt.Println("candidate master")
case rating >= 1600:
    fmt.Println("expert")
case rating >= 1400:
    fmt.Println("pupil")
case rating < 1400:
    fmt.Println("newbie")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you're basically repeating the variable name that already exists above[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlF6g.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).